# Can you build a solver for a language from a solver for its complement?

Tags: turing-machines, semi-decidability

If you have a solver for an L in NP do you have enough information to build a solver for co-L in Co-NP? Meaning, is there a procedure that can take you from a solver for one to a solver for another?

Comment: This is equivalent to whether NP equals coNP.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus how this is true is not entirely clear to me? I do not mean to say the languages L and co-L are equivalent in complexity. Maybe the procedure that takes you from one solver to the other takes a very long time or it always produces a solver that takes a lot longer to compute? I just mean to ask if one has the information content of the other.

Comment: Oh, I see - I got it wrong. If a language is in NP then its complement is in coNP. The “solver” (usually called *verifier*) is essentially identical.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to define what you mean by a "solver", specifically?  Do you want everything to run in polynomial time?